# DynamoDB sort order of Date RangeKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

I have a DynamoDB table with the following key values: A simple string id as `HashKey` and a string representing a Date as `RangeKey`. The date string is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

I am now wondering how DynamoDB orders its entries. When I query for multiple `RangeKey` values on the same `HashKey` the result is ordered by the date ascending.

However, according to the Dynamo [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) it will order all non-integer RangeKeys considering their UTF-8 byte values.

When I now save the following RangeKey entries:

1. `2019-01-01`
2. `2018-12-04`
3. `2018-12-05`

The output of a simple `DynamoDBMapper.query(...)` results in the correct order:

1. `2018-12-04`
2. `2018-12-05`
3. `2019-01-01`

Is Dynamo ordering the RangeKeys by date or is the byte value calculated a way that it matches with the date representation?

Comment: You may want to convert it to epoch before storing and use that as sortkey.

Comment: True. But I'm wondering why the sorting/ordering currently still works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its sorting it in UTF-8 bytes. It has no idea that you are sorting dates, to DynamoDB, its just a string.

Comment: That's what I thought and read. But I still can't explain why it currently sorts as expected.

Comment: 4 > 5 and 9 > 8. The way you chose to create the date is year-month-day, this will always correctly sort the dates using byte code. If it was day-month-year, then it would not work.

Comment: @GaryHoliday, are you saying storing in year-month-date will always work? I am still not clear how. Secondly, what does it mean 4>5 in your comment

Comment: @curiousengineer Since the dates are stored as year-month-day, it will always be correctly sorted by UTF-8 bytes. When I say 4 > 5, it is a mistake, what I meant was 4 < 5 and 9 > 8. 

It only works when you sort by year-month-day, if you sorted by day-month-year, it would not work.